# Horizontal distance between images

Tags: minipage

I am trying to control the horizontal space between two minipages but it is ignored.

```
    \begin{figure}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.6\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[scale=0.42]{image1.png}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hspace{0.5cm}
    % \hspace*{0.5cm} does not work as well
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.6\linewidth}
     \includegraphics[scale=0.42]{image2.png}

    \end{minipage}
     \caption{Some caption}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have two minipages whose widths exceed the text width. It's not clear what you are after.

Comment: Your `minipages` are wider than `textwidth`. Why you use `minipages`? You can put your images directly into `figure` environment.

Comment: Additionally, don't use `scale`. Use `width=<dimen>`. With `scale` your images may be wider than the width of `minipage`s.

Comment: You can wrap your minipages by `\fboxes`, it helps to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `minipage`s, I suggest you load the `subcaption` package and place the images into `subfigure` environments. A `subfigure` environment is, for all intents and purposes, a `minipage` environment that lets you add a sub-caption, should you choose to do so, which may be cross-referenced using the usual `\label`-`\ref` method.

Do make sure, though, that the sum of the widths of the `subfigure`s does not exceed `\textwitdth`.

```
...
\usepackage{subcaption}
...   
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image1.png}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{\fill} % achieve maximal horizontal separation of the subfigures
\begin{subfigure}[t]{.45\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image2.png}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given what you appear to be trying to achieve, it may be helpful to wrap them in a tabular environment, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}\centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
   \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{image1.png}
    \end{minipage}
    &
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.45\linewidth}
     \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{image2.png}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{tabular}
     \caption{Some caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```